# sending info to C# class for verification in cshtml

Tags: c#, razor, input, submit

How do I create a call to a C# class which verify that the username and password are correct and then return the result to this razor page?

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/_Layout_Main.cshtml";
}


<div id="Login_Wrapper">
    <p>
        Brugernavn/Email:
    </p>
    <input type="text" name="brugernavn" id="brugernavn" placeholder="Brugernavn/email" />

    <p>
        Password:
    </p>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Where's your code? What you're looking for is already in the template of an MVC internet site in Visual Studio. Try it, if you get stuck then ask a question.

Comment: [Razor Tutorial-suggested good reading](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)

Comment: You may want to clarify what "correct" means. You're probably referring to some sort of validation, which can be achieved via DataAnnotations. Ensuring the values aren't null, have a minimum length, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to do it whould be with a postback call

the code will look like this:

```
@{
    Page.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/_Layout.cshtml";

    if(IsPost)
    {
        string username = Request["username"]; // the request calls the input named "username"

        // here you can type in any C# code you wish
    }
}

<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="submit" value="btn2" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the same view in the action method which will be called on submitting the form.
You can store the result in session or viewbag etc.. and display the result from it.